# How to stop Intellij from creating src/main/java and src/main/scala-x folders?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have a SBT project in Intellij 15.0.2 for scala only programming.

For some reason, the project keeps creating the following folders in my project:

- src/main/java
- src/main/scala-2.10
- src/main/scala-2.11
- src/test/java
- src/test/scala-2.10
- src/test/scala-2.11

I have attempted to remove them by unchecking them as "Sources" or "Tests" in my Project Structure and then deleting the folders. But they are immediately re-created by Intellij ...

Comment: Vesion of Intellij and Scala plugin please? Can you share build.sbt?

Comment: I updated the post with the Build.scala and version. Intellij version: 15.0.2

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can disable this while creating/importing sbt project (there is a suitable checkbox).

If project is already created, you can go to

> Settings |> Build, Execution, Deployment |> Build Tools |> SBT

and uncheck `Create directores for empty content roots automatically`

This option is kind of usefull if you are starting a new project as it will create directories for you, but after this I suggest to disable this option and keep only directories you want, otherways directories will be generated each time you build/refresh project.

See picture:

[image]

## Edit

Seems like this option disappeared from Idea interface. If you have an old project and it is enabled there, go to `.idea/sbt.xml` and get rid of

```
<option name="createEmptyContentRootDirectories" value="true" />
```

Comment: It stopped creating the directories. But still creating "Content Root" entries for them in "Project Structure". Any idea how to stop it?

Comment: I have no idea how to stop it, although I didn't even know about this until now. Does it cause any problems?