# How to prevent sbt from creating source/resource directories in parent project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm setting up a project with two modules, following [this](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Multi-Project.html#Aggregation). I only want the source/resources directory structure in the modules, not in the parent project. How can I achieve that in build.sbt?

Answer (score 1):

sbt will not create source/resources directories in the root folder. It will create a target/project directories, through.

Just make sure that your projects are in different folders.

That is, the source for core should be under the "core" directory:

```
lazy val core = (project in file("core")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    // other settings
  )
```

Your directory structure should be similar to [this](https://github.com/imarios/ToySbtMultiProject) example.

Comment: Indeed sbt wasn't creating them, as you said. It was the IDE (as in my answer). Sorry for not mentioning the IDE in the original question, but I didn't suspect it.

Answer (score 1):

It was actually IntelliJ IDEA creating the folders when clicking "refresh" in the SBT tab. Check this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876995/how-to-stop-intellij-from-creating-src-main-java-and-src-main-scala-x-folders).

Comment: Correct IntelliJ may add the empty folders.